# Merging two dataframes only on certain row's using a mask

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which I can create a mask based on a conditional statement as follows

```
mask = (self.df['Code Assigned'] != 1)
```

I then want merge it with another dataframe using the values left in the filtered column to align the rows

```
self.df = pd.merge(self.df, extraData, left_on=['Code Assigned'], right_on=['CODE'], how='left')
```

If I just place the mask as the first argument in pd.merge, as you would with pd.iloc then I get the following error

> TypeError: merge() got multiple values for argument 'how'

Is there a way I can use the mask to merge, or another way to conditional merge rows of two dataframes?

Edit: I also need to keep all the rows from `self.df` just returning null for all the non-matched, non-filterd rows

Comment: Try `self.df = pd.merge(self.df[mask], extraData, left_on=['Code Assigned'], right_on=['CODE'], how='left')`

Comment: @not_speshal, thank you for the quick response, I would like to keep all the rows from the left dataframe. I have edited my question to clarify this

Comment: Please post samples of `self.df` and `extraData` and your expected output.